# Using BS4 and requests to scrape links of a specific class?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to use requests and BeautifulSoup4 to scrape the top page of r/askreddit, but when I tried to pull links using the class of that link, I would sometimes receive an empty list. Using this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/top/?t=day'
r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a', 'SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z _2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print(links)
```

Sometimes the code would return a printed version of each link as well as a list of the links as intended:

```
/r/AskReddit/comments/yaqpzk/what_is_a_cult_that_pretends_its_not_cult/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yaugmy/whats_a_name_you_would_never_give_to_your_child/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yavldx/what_is_the_single_greatest_animated_series_of/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yb64tg/what_have_you_survived_that_wouldve_killed_you/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yat0xj/what_is_your_favorite_movie_that_most_people_have/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yasntt/what_is_the_craziest_cult_of_all_time/
/r/AskReddit/comments/yas0s7/54_of_americans_between_the_ages_of_16_and_74/
['/r/AskReddit/comments/yaqpzk/what_is_a_cult_that_pretends_its_not_cult/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yaugmy/whats_a_name_you_would_never_give_to_your_child/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yavldx/what_is_the_single_greatest_animated_series_of/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yb64tg/what_have_you_survived_that_wouldve_killed_you/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yat0xj/what_is_your_favorite_movie_that_most_people_have/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yasntt/what_is_the_craziest_cult_of_all_time/', '/r/AskReddit/comments/yas0s7/54_of_americans_between_the_ages_of_16_and_74/']
>>>
```

but most of the time I would simply receive:

```
[]
>>>
```

I am confused as to why the same code would be providing two different outputs, and I don't understand why I only sometimes receive the data I actually want to scrape. I have looked at some of the other posts about these libraries on this site, but I haven't found anything that looks like the problem I am having. I have looked over the BS4 documentation, albeit a bit ineffectively because I am a beginner, but I am still unsure of where the program is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to parse `old.reddit.com` (note the `old.` at the beginning of URL - simpler HTML syntax) or use their JSON API (add `.json` at the end of URL). For example:

```py
import requests

base_url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/top/.json?t=day"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0"
}

data = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers).json()["data"]["children"]

for i, d in enumerate(data, 1):
    print("{:>3} {:<90} {}".format(i, d["data"]["title"], d["data"]["url"]))
```

Prints:

```
  1 What is a cult that pretends it’s not cult?                                                https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yaqpzk/what_is_a_cult_that_pretends_its_not_cult/
  2 Men of Reddit, what was something you didn't know about women till you got with one?       https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb54lt/men_of_reddit_what_was_something_you_didnt_know/
  3 What's a name you would NEVER give to your child?                                          https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yaugmy/whats_a_name_you_would_never_give_to_your_child/
  4 What is the single greatest animated series of all time?                                   https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yavldx/what_is_the_single_greatest_animated_series_of/
  5 What have you survived that would’ve killed you 150+ years ago?                            https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb64tg/what_have_you_survived_that_wouldve_killed_you/
  6 What is your “favorite movie” that most people have never seen?                            https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yat0xj/what_is_your_favorite_movie_that_most_people_have/
  7 What is the craziest cult of all time?                                                     https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yasntt/what_is_the_craziest_cult_of_all_time/
  8 [Serious]: What are some early warning signs of an abusive relationship?                   https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yar1os/serious_what_are_some_early_warning_signs_of_an/
  9 54% of Americans between the ages of 16 and 74 read below a 6th grade reading level. Why do you think that is? https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yas0s7/54_of_americans_between_the_ages_of_16_and_74/
 10 What is something positive going on in your life?                                          https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb28sm/what_is_something_positive_going_on_in_your_life/
 11 The alien overlords demand that one American major metropolitan city be sacrificed and turned into a no human zone. Which one goes? https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb0l7y/the_alien_overlords_demand_that_one_american/
 12 What movie has a great soundtrack in your opinion?                                         https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yapb09/what_movie_has_a_great_soundtrack_in_your_opinion/
 13 What is an obscure reference to something that only true fans will understand?             https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb7og2/what_is_an_obscure_reference_to_something_that/
 14 What's socially acceptable within your own gender, but not with the opposite?              https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb7pei/whats_socially_acceptable_within_your_own_gender/
 15 What stages of drunk do you have?                                                          https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb39tn/what_stages_of_drunk_do_you_have/
 16 What is the worst chocolate?                                                               https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yawn49/what_is_the_worst_chocolate/
 17 What would the US state mottos be if they were brutally honest?                            https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb5eaw/what_would_the_us_state_mottos_be_if_they_were/
 18 What’s your opinion on circumcision?                                                       https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yat9pm/whats_your_opinion_on_circumcision/
 19 What examples of 'Internet etiquette' do you feel deserve more awareness?                  https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb25n3/what_examples_of_internet_etiquette_do_you_feel/
 20 What 90s song will always be a banger?                                                     https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/ybeys0/what_90s_song_will_always_be_a_banger/
 21 What show never had a 'meh' season?                                                        https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb4ww4/what_show_never_had_a_meh_season/
 22 What was the scariest thing you have witnessed?                                            https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb0ajj/what_was_the_scariest_thing_you_have_witnessed/
 23 You start a new job, what's an instant red flag in the workplace social atmosphere?        https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb2siq/you_start_a_new_job_whats_an_instant_red_flag_in/
 24 which fictional world would you like to live in the most?                                  https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yawtqi/which_fictional_world_would_you_like_to_live_in/
 25 How did you come up with your username?                                                    https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/yb7zm8/how_did_you_come_up_with_your_username/
```